# Can you find an Hermetic Seal instead of dying at the beginning of the Leviathan expedition?

Tags: no-mans-sky

The Leviathan expedition involves a weir permadeath mechanic that wraps the player in a loop, with progression made easier on each death by some unlocked rewards that persist between different iterations.

In order to teach the player about the mechanic, the player starts without the plans for the Hermetic Seal, a component that will be required in order to repair their damaged ship right at the start of the game. The tutorial then suggests that the player should die in order to unlock the relative reward - the Seal crafting recipe - and thus be able to repair the ship on their "second loop".

To complete the expedition the player has to complete each milestone, and thus they will have to complete the "Die once" requirement at some point. Since every iteration completely resets the player advancement **including** the completed milestones (making the "Die once" the only milestone that "sticks" - since you automatically complete it when you "rebirth") this also means that the player can't avoid dying at least once to fully complete the expedition - and the sooner they die the better since death means they **will** lose whatever accomplished on that iteration.

Yet, I was wondering how far the game goes in order to avoid the player getting an Hermetic Seal by any other means. In the normal gameplay the game will "cheat" to never provide some techs to the player before reaching some story milestones (for example, never giving you access to the hyperdrive)... Do we know if the expedition employs any similar technique? While that would be an exercise in futility, could a stubborn player try to reach a trading outpost to buy an Hermetic Seal there or workaround the need completely by purchasing another ship? Or will the game find a way to prevent that from happening (suspiciously, the starting planet is also a "wormed" one. While Giant Worms normally can't harm the player, I wouldn't put that past the developers to add a "scripted death" if the player goes too far from their ship).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to survive long enough for a random trader to land nearby, I also happened to pick up a shock crystal from a geode, glad I kept it, gave me enough to exchange ships.

Then I played not knowing the expedition would reset upon death, luckily

> There is a fake death towards the end of the expedition that counts. So yes, you don't have to die at all, lol.